# Variable number of pages in page control

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I am pulling in an array of variables from Parse to populate a collection view. Depending on the screen size, it will be a variable number of pages since more things can fit on bigger screens. Is it possible to have a variable number of pages depending on the number of elements, rather than hard-code it in storyboard? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create an `IBOutlet` for the page control and set the value in code whenever you determine how many pages there are.  This is the same thing you would do to adjust anything you create in your storyboard from your code.

Here is a bit of [documentation on creating such a connection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html).